Tag [swiftdata] should replace [swift-data]
The name of the new Apple technology is "SwiftData" not "Swift Data".

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftdata/

Somewhat confusing, as it's "Core Data" and not "CoreData".
Tasks:

swiftdata should be added as the primary tag
Current tag swift-data should be changed to a synonym
coredata should be added as a synonym of core-data




swiftdata should be added as the primary tag


Done: renamed swift-data to swiftdata.


Current tag swift-data should be changed to a synonym


This isn't strictly necessary - tags cannot differ by only a dash.  However, done for the sake of existing links to the tag that may exist.


coredata should be added as a synonym of core-data


Not necessary, as described above, and no existing incorrectly named tag, so not done.

Thank you. Re: [tag:core-data] / [tag:coredata], you don't think this is a bad experience? Shouldn't that link to the proper tag / isn't that the purpose of synonyms?
